# Why the error message 'Cannot use positional argument...' when unpacking an associative array with mixed string and int keys?

Tags: php

The following will not compile because of the mix of int and string keys:

```
function func(...$array) {}

func(...[ 'a' => 'A', 2 => 'B', 'c' => 'C' ]);
```

Why is the error thrown: *Cannot use positional argument after named argument during unpacking?*

Please note that my question is not: Why is *this* error thrown?, but why is this specific error message given, which to me seems unrelated to the actual reason (the mix of int and string keys)?

Comment: The mix of int and string keys sounds correct. The first argument is a named argument (`a`, as in: `func(a: 'A')`), then the next is a positional argument (`2` as in `func(..., ..., 'B')`) and these can only be mixed if positional arguments come first (`func('B', a: 'A')` would work, whereas `func(a: 'A', 'B')` wouldn't work).

Comment: Named parameters require an _identifier_ as the parameter name, and `2` is not a valid identifier in PHP. Therefor this _can not_ be interpreted as a named parameter to begin with. Int vs string has little to do with this, you could make the key `'2'`, and would still have the same issue.

Comment: @CBroe, I think if he made the key `'0'` (or `0`) and placed it at the beginning of the array, it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have [Argument Unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) combined with [Named Arguments](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params). This case is explained at [Variadic functions and argument unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params#variadic_functions_and_argument_unpacking):

> The foo(...$args) unpacking syntax from the argument unpacking RFC also supports unpacking named arguments.

> Any value with a string key is unpacked as a named argument. Integers keys are treated as normal positional arguments (with the integer value being ignored).

> Argument unpacking is also subject to the general rule that positional arguments must always precede named arguments.